# Estimating the effect of a treatment on a growth trajectory using propensity scores

Tags: mixed-model, propensity-scores

I want to estimate the effect of a treatment on a subsequent growth trajectory, allowing both the level and rate of change in the response variable to depend on the treatment.

To adjust for pre-treatment covariates I would like to use some sort of propensity score based adjustment, whether matching, covariate adjustment on the propensity score, inverse probability weighting, or stratification.

The problem that I have is that although I can estimate the models easily enough, I have no idea whether the parameter estimates will be unbiased and/or the standard errors correct - I haven't seen any applications of propensity score methods with repeated-measures for the outcome variable, so I'm not sure if this is something that I shouldn't do? Has there been any research about the performance of different PS methods in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still unknown how to estimate standard errors for PS analysis, and no methodological papers have described the use of PSs in this way to my knowledge. Leite, Sandbach, Jin, MacInnes, & Jackman (2012) described a method very similar using longitudinal growth models, so you might want to look into that. Ganz, Kwan, Stanton, Bower & Belin (2011) and Binder, White, Resnick, McClellan, Lei & Ouslander (2012) used an approach similar to what you describe.